# Individual increment for Tensorflow global_step with Estimator API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

again I have a question regarding Tensorflow. For various reasons I want to have a variable representing not the number of steps done by the optimizer, but the number of samples processed (which would correspond to the optimizer steps in case of batchsize = 1).

I think best fitting would be using the global_step variable, because it is already existing and automatically loaded/saved by the Estimator API.
Is there a possibility to specifiy the increment size dynamically or is there a way to achieve the same save/restore behaviour with a newly created variable?

Important is the compatibility with the Tensorflow Estimator API.

-- Edit for clarification for the reason

I want to experiment with batchsizes changing during experimentation. Generally this is possible with Tensorflow. Batchsizes are varied on a dynamic way, thus a simple computation/sum of the values will not be possible

--

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Could you explain your use-case a little more please? E.g. why does global_steps*batch_size not suffice for you? Why do you need a count of the number of samples?

Comment: I want to experiment with batchsizes changing during experimentation. Generally this is possible with Tensorflow. Batchsizes are varied on a dynamic way, thus a simple computation/sum of the values will not be possible.

Comment: Why not multiply tf.train.global_step() with your batch_size?

Comment: As I tried to explain in the previous comment the batchsize is not constant, therefore batchsize * global_step does not yield the correct result.

Comment: You can get the "dynamic" batch size via tf.shape(inputs)[0] (assuming axis 0 of your inputs is the batch axis).

Comment: Getting the dynamic batch size is not really the problem, getting the sum of all dynamic batchsizes over several train/val iterations with the Estimator API is the main cause of trouble.